# How can I create thumbnail for a video in android apilevel > 14?

Tags: android, video, bitmap, thumbnails

I want to create thumbnail for a video, I tried this method:

`Bitmap bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(mediaFile.getAbsolutePath(), MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);`

However, this return `null` in apilevel > 14. So how can I get thumbnail for a video in apilevel > 14?

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap thumb = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(getContentResolver(), id, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
```

Comment: What should I do with the `id`, the document seems a little bit confusing:`origId: Original image id associated with thumbnail of interest.`